# Interrupting k-pager-nav with pop-up modal to confirm/deny moving to a new page.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Background**

So, I have a WebApp built on kendo, bootstrap, and backbone that has a grid which displays data that is stored in a data base. The grid has a data source binding with serverPaging turned on.

*DataSource*

`alertDataSource = new kendo.Backbone.DataSource({
                        collection: this.options.collection,
                        batch: false,
                        page: 1,
                        pageSize: 50,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        .....`

*Grid*

`batchDetailsGrid = $("#batchDetailsGrid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: alertDataSource,
                            dataBound: onAccountDataBound,
                            name: "AccountList",
                            autoBind: false,
                            height: 450,
                            ...`

On the bottom of the grid there are kendo navigator icons that can move you from page to page.

**The problem**

I need to find a way to alert the user that they are about to move to the next page (using a modal which I have already defined). But it seems that once you hit a pager icon it already starts the process of retrieving more data.

Does anyone know if there is any way to get in front of the kendo pager functionality that would allow a user to decide whether to stay on the same page or move forward.

Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/confirm-page-change-on-kendo-grid

They're using kendo UI for MVC but here's the reference for that event in the JavaScript version of kendo: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestStart

Post a comment if you need more help

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this?